# How configure Buster.js for javascript TDD (only browser without Node.js)

Tags: javascript, tdd, configuration-files, buster.js

could someone explain to me how conigure buster.js to test my javascript scripts.
I have two javacript lib Mootools and jQuery, but I don't use node.js.
I didn't catch how make a config file:

```
var config = module.exports;

config["myTests"] = {
    environment: "browser",  // or "node"
    libs: ["../*.js"],
    sources: ["src/core.js", "src/**/*.js"],
    tests: ["test/**/*.js", "!test/**/*integration-test.js"]
};
```

What have I write into libs, sources and tests?
Does "libs" mean Mootools and jQuery (my case) javascript library?
Does "sources" mean javascript files of mine?
Does "tests" mean javascript file where I'm gonna test my scripts files?

Comment: From what i can tell, BusterJS actually requires Node itself. It's not just a test library - it tries to support headless as well as browser-acquired testing, and for that it needs to run its own server (via Node)

Comment: Yes but how configure the file? Read the last three lines, is it right?

Comment: The answers to your questions are: yes, yes, and yes